# Foreach remover images duplicadas

Tags: php, array, magento

Tenho código abaixo que puxa as imagens dos produtos do carrinho de compras do magento, porém ele está exibindo duplicado, ou seja, quando ele lista as imagens ele exibe duas vezes a mesma imagem.

```
<?php 
    $items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems() ;  

        foreach($items as $item) {                                   
            echo '<img style="width: 75px; height: 75px;" src="'.$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($item->getProduct(), 'small_image').'"/>';

        }

?>
```

Gostaria de exibir apenas umas vez, acabar com esse *loop*.

Answer (score 1):

`array_unique($array)`

```
<?php 
    $items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems() ;  

    $items = array_unique($items);

        foreach($items as $item) {                                   
            echo '<img style="width: 75px; height: 75px;" src="'.$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($item->getProduct(), 'small_image').'"/>';

        }

?>
```

Comment: Cara vlw pela ajuda, mais mesmo assim não funcionou ainda, ele continua duplicando.

Comment: Então o problema está antes. Ao adicionar o produto no carrinho é preciso adicionar uma vez apenas.

Comment: Então também pensei nisso, mais está certo,  problema é que ele duplicando apenas imagens, por exemplo se tem um produto ele exibe uma imagem só e se tem dois produtos ele lista duas vezes e se tenho 3 produtos ele vai lista 3 vezes.

Comment: Faz um `count($items)` em baixo do `$items`. É pra trazer a quantidade de produtos no carrinho.

Comment: Poderia me ajudar em como fazer esse count

Comment: que estou com pouco de dificuldade nisso